# Passing parameter to displaytemplate between different views

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have several views with different viewmodels.

Every view has "ProjectId" dropdownlist, and I want to show selected project's start date beside the "ProjectId" dropdownlist before submit.

And the "ProjectId" dropdownlist is a ViewBag.

Is there any other way besides adding start date to each viewmodel?

view:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    Project:
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", new SelectList(ViewBag.ProjectsDropDownList, "Value", "Text"))
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code that you tried.

Comment: you could use AJAX to fetch the start date of the project from the server, after it's been selected by the user. Or put the start date as a data-attribute of the options in the dropdown, and use Javascript to display it when it's selected. or put it in the viewmodel. Or in a separate dictionary in the viewbag. Lots of ways. Probably some more I haven't thought of too. use your imagination.

Comment: @ADyson I know I could use AJAX to fetch the date, but also mean all views have to add AJAX, later I found displaytemplate this way that could call the same template to render html, but I don't know how to passing parameter and use with different viewmodels.

Comment: It might be better to use the viewbag to hold the dates, so you don't have to worry about the specific model.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to answer you without you supplying your code but I have had a look at
https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/viewbag-in-asp.net-mvc regarding viewbags which you are welcome to have a look at.

It shows that you could simply use a label with something like this in the front end:

```
          <label>Project Start Date:</label>  @ViewBag.projectStartDate
```

That would be if you are using ASP.NET or HTML for the client side coding

In the back end something like this :

```
     namespace MVC_BasicTutorials.Controllers
     {
         public class ProjectController : Controller
         {
            string projectName;
            int projectId;
            string projectDate;
    
            public ProjectController ()
            {
               projectName = "new project";
               projectId = 0;
               projectDate = "01-01-1990";
            }
    
            public ActionResult returnDate()
            {
                ViewBag.projectStartDate = this.projectDate;
                return View();
            }

        }
     }
```

Comment: If http method is GET the projectId will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

The last approach I used:

ProjectsController:

```
    public PartialViewResult ProjectDate(int projectId)
    {
      // get project start date
      ViewBag.StartDate = startDate;

      return PartialView("_ProjectDate");
    }
```

_ProjectDate.cshtml:

```
// use ViewBag.StartDate to render html what I want
```

get_start_date.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var projectId = $('#ProjectId').val();
if (projectId != undefined) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Projects/GetProjectDate',
        data: { ProjectId: projectId },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#project_date").html(result);
        }
    });
}});
```

_Layout.cshtml import get_start_date.js, and insert this code in the page I need:

```
    <div id="project_date"></div>
```